# more than one implicit conversion in scala

Tags: scala

I want to have 2 implicit comvertors in scala

1. To convert string to int
2. To convert int to float

   ```
   implicit def String2Int(v: String): Int = Integer.parseInt(v)
   ```

The above works but when I write below

```
 implicit def String2Float(v: String): Float = v.toFloat
```

It gives compile error **cannot resolve symbol to Float**

Can we not have 2 implicit converters in one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scala, `String` does not have `toInt, toFloat`, etc methods. Where are they taken from?

Scala has Predef object which is imported implicitly in every source (even if you are not importing it).

Predef has the following method:

```
@inline implicit def augmentString(x: String): StringOps = new StringOps(x)
```

So it **implicitly** converts any value of type `String` to `StringOps`.

`StringOps` defines methods:

```
def toInt: Int         = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(toString)
def toFloat: Float     = java.lang.Float.parseFloat(toString)
...
```

So when you write `str.toFloat` - the compiler actually converts `String` to `StringOps` and calls the appropriate method.

Ok. What is the problem with your code?

```
implicit def String2Float(v: String): Float = v.toFloat
```

Compiler tries to find something that has `.toFloat`, it finds it in `StringOps` and in `Float`  via `String2Float` method. (`Float` also has `toFloat` method).

Compiler "didn't add" the method `toFloat` (of `Predef`) to `String` because it cannot decide which implicit conversion to apply and implicit conversion from `String` to `StringOps` is broken.

So `String` does not have `toFoat` method anymore and that's why you have error (**cannot resolve symbol to Float** )

(Actually, you should have 2 errors: 
**Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous: ...** AND **value toFloat is not a member of String**)

Solution is to use

```
implicit def String2Float(v: String): Float = java.lang.Float.parseFloat(v)
```

Like you did in `Int` case.

Now it converts `String` to `Float` directly, without implicit conversions (like it was in `v.toFloat` case)

P.S. Thank @Dima for pointing to mistake in my answer.

Comment: `The compiler now sees 2 methods which can convert String to Float` - this is incorrect. It is not trying to convert a `String` to `Float` to begin with. It's trying to convert it into something that has a method `.toFloat`. Now, _this_ can now be done in two ways - either convert to `StringOps` using `augmentString` or to a `Float`, using `String2Float` (because `Float` also has a `toFloat` method). That's' where the ambiguity comes from.

Comment: @Dima, yes, you are right, thanks, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define String2Float as:

```
implicit def String2Float(v: String): Float = {
  val i:Int = v
  i.toFloat
}
```

or pass implicit converter as:

```
implicit def String2Float(v: String)(implicit f: String => Int): Float = {
  v.toFloat
}
```

or get the converter instance implicitly:

```
implicit def String2Float(v: String): Float = {
  val f = implicitly[String => Int]
  f(v).toFloat
}
```

In this case compiler resolves everything successfully